# Variable substitution assuming first occurrence value

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm using variable substitution in a script, however, even though called at different times, the variable assumes the first value that was generated. For example:

```
#!/bin/sh
vardate=$(date)

echo hour is "$vardate"
sleep 5
echo hour is "$vardate"
```

I always get the same output. How can the second occurrence of the substitution be generated at that time?

Thank you!

Comment: Just use `echo hour is $(date)` otherwise the variable will always hold the value at the time it was initialised.

Comment: Thanks @jasonwryan but this was just an example. The actual code is something that I have to use variable substitution. It's basically a bunch of openssl arguments with output manipulation via grep and sed.

Comment: The principle is the same: the variable will have to be updated.

Comment: Can I clear the value before using it again?

Comment: You can assign the variable again. It would be better to make a function instead.

Comment: Proposed answer worked as expected. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you will use the solution of @jasonwryan

```
echo hour is $(date)
```

or you will make it a function:

```
function dt {
vardate=$(date)
echo "hour is $vardate"
}

dt
sleep 5
dt
```

One line test:

```
function dt { var=$(date);echo $var;};dt;sleep 5;dt
```